# React Native hooks - correct use of useEffect()?

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, react-functional-component

I'm new to hooks and ran across this setup on SO and wanted to confirm that this is the correct pattern. I was getting the RN "unmounted component" leak warning message before and this seemed to solve it. I'm trying to mimic in some way `compnentDidMount`. This is part of a phone number verify sign up flow and onMount I want to just check for `navigation` and then fire off a side effect, set mounted `true` and then unmount correctly.

```
const SMSVerifyEnterPinScreen = ({ route, navigation }) => {

  const [didMount, setDidMount] = useState(false)
  const { phoneNumber } = route.params

  useEffect(() => {
    if(navigation) {
      signInWithPhoneNumber(phoneNumber)
      setDidMount(true)
    }
    return () => setDidMount(false)
  }, [])

  if (!didMount) { return null }

  async function signInWithPhoneNumber(phoneNumber) {
    const confirmation = await auth().signInWithPhoneNumber('+1'+phoneNumber)
    ...
  }

  return (
    ...
  )
}
```

RN 0.62.2 with react-nav 5 - thanks!

Comment: What is the purpose of `didMount` . It doesn't seem to accomplish anything. Are you setting some state in `signInWithPhoneNumber`

Comment: yes setting several state in `signInWithPhoneNumber`

Answer (score 1):

Since signInWithPhoneNumber is a async function and will setState you will see warning it the component is unmounted before the response is available

In order to handle such scenarios you can keep a variable to keep track whether its mounted or not and then only set state is the mounted variable is true

However you do not need to return null if component has unmounted since that doesn't accomplish anything. The component is removed from view and will anyways not render anything.

Also you do not need to maintain this value in state, instead use a ref

```
const SMSVerifyEnterPinScreen = ({ route, navigation }) => {

  const isMounted = useRef(true)
  const { phoneNumber } = route.params

  useEffect(() => {
    if(navigation) {
      signInWithPhoneNumber(phoneNumber)
    }
    return () => {isMounted.current = false;}
  }, [])


  async function signInWithPhoneNumber(phoneNumber) {
    const confirmation = await auth().signInWithPhoneNumber('+1'+phoneNumber)
    ...
  }

  return (
    ...
  )
}
```